# how to convert a given utc output in rest api to localtime which is user readable?

Tags: angular, rest, api

In an angular project i have used api from news-api.org. the output of one of these api containes a key-value pair of Utc, ex: publishedAt:2019-06-20T05:49:29Z.

i wanted to use this inside my html component using interpolation. but when i use it with interpolation i get the same output hence the time is not in user readable format. How to convert it to user readable format inside html component.

also when i used the content key from api using interpolation it displays "[+1666 chars]". how to remove it?

```
sample output of this api is:
  "articles": [
    {
        "source": {
            "id": null,
            "name": "Moneycontrol.com"
        },
        "author": null,
        "title": "Market Live: Indices recover with Nifty above 11,700", 
        "description": "Except energy and metal all other sectoral 
        indices are trading lower led by the IT, auto, FMCG and pharma.",
        "url": 
          "https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/markets/market- 
           live-sgx- 
         nifty-dalal-street-bse-nse-nifty-sensex-2-4117401.html",
        "urlToImage": "https://static-news.moneycontrol.com/static- 
         mcnews/2018/08/Sensex_Nifty_BSE_Stock-Market-770x433.jpg",
        "publishedAt": "2019-06-20T05:51:30Z",
        "content": "Brokerages View: Source- CNBC-TV18:\r\nCLSA India 
         StrategyMay indicators show economy stayed weakDomestic demand- 
         linked 
         imports have also been persistently weakEco weakness could be 
         more 
        structural RBI has taken cognizance of slower growthFiscal space 
        is 
        limite… [+1666 chars]"
    },
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: thank you for helping me to change utc to redable format. This article was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use date pipe

```
{{ yourdate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd mm:ss'}}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fv1jap

Comment: how to delete last few characters of content value?

Comment: can you provide the content? did you try trim() ?

Comment: i found at a hack for preventing the display of last few characters of content value using angular slic pipe.   https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe  .                   
 used it like this  {{content|slice:0:-13}}